# Passport authentication doesnot seems to be working

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

**This is my MiddleWare for Passport.js the issue i am getting here i cant logged in getting no errors, register route is working successfully i am entering the Right Credentials and everything from my view is great but i am not redirecting to anywhere i tried i am getting http:500 error and getting NO Select query where username='username' and password='password'**

```
//Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport)
//Passport MiddleWare
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**This is my passport.js file code**

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {

         models.User.findOne({
             where:{username: username}
         }.then(function (err,user) {

            if(err) console.log(err);

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found!'});
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);

                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password.'});
                }
            });


         })
        )

    }));


    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

**this is my login method in route**

```
/*
*Post Login
*/
router.post('/login',function(req,res,next){

  passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect:'/',
    failureRedirect:'/admin/pages',
    failureFlash:true
  })(req,res,next);

})
```

**This is my user.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var models=require('../models');
var passport=require('passport');
var bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');


//Get Register
router.get('/register',function(req,res){
res.render('register',{
  title:'Register'
})
});

/*
* Register Post
*/

router.post('/register',function(req,res){

     var name=req.body.name;
     var email=req.body.email;
     var username=req.body.username;
     var password=req.body.password;
     var password2=req.body.password2;

     models.User.findOne({
       where:{username:username}
     }).then(function(copyuser){
       if(copyuser){
         console.log('User already exist');
          redirect('/users/login');
       }
       else{
        var user={
          name: name,
          email: email,
          username: username,
          password: password,
          admin: 0
        };

    //  res.json(user);
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,function(err,salt){
      bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,function(err,hash){

        user.password=hash;

          models.User.create(user).then(function(user){
            res.json(user);
          })



          console.log('You are now registered');
          res.redirect('/admin/pages')


    })
  })
       }
     })

})

/*
* Get Login
*/
router.get('/login',function(req,res){
  if(res.locals.user) res.redirect('/');

  res.render('login',{
    title:'log in'
  })

})

/*
*Post Login
*/
router.post('/login',function(req,res,next){

  passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect:'/',
    failureRedirect:'/admin/pages',
    failureFlash:true
  })(req,res,next);

})

//Exports
module.exports=router;
```

Comment: why do you use `models.User.findOne`. models variable is undefined in this context right ?. so it should `User.findOne`

Comment: can you post your User class as well please

Comment: I have Update user.js route  -NuOne T

Comment: did you replace `models.User.findOne` with `User.findOne` in your code

Comment: in passport.js  can you catch after then? and console.log(error) see if there are erros or console.log(user) inside then right away to see if your gets there without error ? it looks like it should be `User.findOne` and not models.User because you didn't require models in passport.js